# Periodically backup files to another server via scp

Tags: scp

There are set of log files that have a pattern xxxxxYYY where xxxx -> some text and YYY is a sequence number increasing sequentially by one and wrapping around. Only the last n number of files are available at a given time.

I would like to write a foolproof script that would make sure that all the log files are backed up in another server (via ssh/scp).

Can somebody please suggest a logic/code snippet(perl or shell) for it?

=> The script can run every few minutes to ensure bursts of traffic do not cause log files to miss getting backed up.

=> The roll over needs to be detected so that files are not overwritten in the destination server/directory.

-> I do not have super user either in source or destination boxes. The destiantion box does not have rsync installed and would take too long to get it installed.
-> Only one log file gets updated at a time.

Comment: @steven: I don't think so - "I would like to write a...script" is programming.

Comment: how often is a new file started?  are lots of the files "in use" at once or is only one ever going to be changing at a time?

Comment: What do you want to have happen when the number wraps around? A new destination directory created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look at having `cron` run an `rsync --backup` command.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about rsync. he destination box is alpha and it doesn't have rsync installed. I'll look at rsync tonight to see if it can be just run from my login without any installation.( by explicitly specifying the path)